# 500 Internal Server Error on XHR Request

Tags: javascript, mysql, xml, xmlhttprequest

Here is my code:

```
var fd = new FormData(document.querySelector('#form-step1'));
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('POST', '/Handlers/newAccount_handler.php', true);

xhr.send(fd); // this line is causing a 500 Internal Server Error and the data is not saved to the MySQL table
```

Why is the last line causing a 500 Internal Server Error? Is there anything wrong with the code or do I need to log anything first to see?

Comment: Are you sure '/Handlers/newAccount_handler.php' is the right location. Give us your file tree of your server.

Comment: Is this a JS problem, a MySQL problem, or an XML problem? What have you tried to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the last line. The '500 Internal Server Error' is simply the result the server sends back as the result of the request.

This means that '/Handlers/newAccount_handler.php' is the real problem. If you open this URL in a browser it will show you an error.

Comment: Hi @sander_p, the file does exist and if I navigate to it on my browser, it does open.

Comment: In that case, when running the above code, use your browser to see what's going on. With Chrome, press F12, then go to the Network tab, press F5 and click on the line for 'newAccount_handler.php'. There you should be able to find the error.

Comment: F12, F5...amazing tip for troubleshooting ajax with chrome.  thank you.

Comment: Can you tell us, why Chrome doesn't show that error text, what we see that error-message, when we  manually open the url.

Comment: I had the same error when trying to test on my localhost.  In my case I used php `break` outside a 'loop' or 'switch' context which caused an error inside my php file and consequently Internal Server Error 500 for my xmlhttprequest.  This lead me actually to 'catch' the error within the xmlhttprequest 'load' event and setting custom error message for the client in case of such an error.

Answer (score 1):

This seems a bit old, but I've had similar issue. It's worth checking what the value of '#form-step1' you are sending. In my case if the value contained quotes it would throw an error, but with simple text it worked fine.